# How to get current postion of control in UIscrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to get current position of control in uiscrollview, after uiscrollview scrolled by some value.

Comment: What do you mean by control? Do you want to get the `UIScrollView`'s current position? `contentOffset` is what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The position of your control in scrollview does not actually change with scrolling. So:

`yourSubview.frame` is always fixed. You can check how much of the content is scrolled in scrollview by looking at: `scrollview.contentOffset` the contentOffset as you might guess starts default at CGPoint : (0,0) After you scroll this value gets updated accordingly.